# Wordpress website Critical Issue - Content size comprised

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, namecheap

My WordPress website has suddenly got an error. I haven't changed anything in the past few weeks but suddenly the content is compressed.

```
wordpress version: 5.7.1
Theme: generatepress
php version: 7.2.34
hosting: namecheap
PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getWpContentDir() 
on null in /home/perfhmgp/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-fastest-cache- 
premium/pro/library/widget-cache.php:103
```

[image]

at the end of the page, it is showing the following error.
"There has been a critical error on this website."

[image]

Comment: Try updating the PHP version and update the theme and plugins. See if that helps. Otherwise, try to restore the website from the backup.

Comment: There is no useful information here.  At the very least, get the error message from your error log.

Comment: WordPress 5.7 requires PHP version 7.4.x. You have PHP version 7.2.x. Read this link: https://wordpress.org/about/requirements/

Answer (score 0):

I was using premium wp fastest cache which was outdated. I have disabled the premium version and now my site is working perfectly.

case of error:

```
PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getWpContentDir() on null in /home/perfhmgp/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-fastest-cache- premium/pro/library/widget-cache.php:103
```

Comment: This is not a good answer. WP Fastest Cache is not outdated. Your installation might be. Your installation of PHP is out of date. Proper maintenance of your server and software is a required procedure for any public-facing system.